# Manually updating a plugin , is it overriding the previous settings of the plugin?

Tags: plugins, updates

This is basiscly what i can't figure out ! I have some plugins that cant be updated automatically, so i want to update a plugin manually by replacing it with the newest version through ftp.

maybe a noob questions but i really dont know. So does this override all settings i previously made with the plugin ? (since all files are replaced by the new version?)

Comment: Is this actually a `wordpress.com` issue? If so, it is off topic per our [FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: sorry, deleted the tag!

Answer (score 1):

Plugin settings are generally saved via the WordPress database.

For example, if you were manually updating the plugin Contact Form 7 via your FTP, your form settings would not be overwritten because these live in the database.

However, if you have edited the core plugin files via your server (this includes style alterations or other code edits), those changes will be overwritten.

If you're planning on editing the plugin files, you should use hooks and filters within functions.php instead. This means that any customisation won't be lost when updating the plugin (manually or automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So hooks and filters are basicly the same for plugins what a childtheme is to themes?

Comment: Pretty much! You can read more about filters and hooks here: http://wpcandy.com/teaches/how-to-use-wordpress-hooks. If my answer was helpful, please mark it as answered.

Comment: Assuming that hooks are implemented in the plugin, which is all too rare.